# Qml TableView - TableViewColumn - ListModel - access nested objects

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qtquick2

Currently some students and I are programming a little application with QtQuick.

We have the following `TableView`:

```
TableView {
    model: ListModel {
        id: orderListModel
        Component.onCompleted: {
            var tOrderList = orderController.getOrderList();
            for(var i = 0; i < tTicketList.length; ++i){
                orderListModel.append(tOrderList[i]);
            }
        }
    }


    TableViewColumn {
        role: "orderId"
        title: "Auftragsnummer"
        width: 100
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "customer.name"
        title: "Kunde"
        width: 100
    }
}
```

`getOrderList` returns a `QList<Object*>` with all the orders.
The `Order` class has a property `customer`

```
Q_PROPERTY(Customer* customer READ getCustomer NOTIFY customerChanged)
```

which in turns has a property called `name`.

We would like to show the latter property inside the `TableView` but unfortunately only the `orderId` property of `Order` does works.

What value should have the second role? How can we access data of the nested object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model) you can use `QList<QObject*>` as a model for a view directly, without manually copying the data as you did. In particular:

> **The QObject* is available as the modelData property**. As a convenience, the **properties of the object are also made available directly** in the delegate's context.

Considering [the example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-models-objectlistmodel-example.html) linked in the documentation we have that a property of the `QObject` can be used as role in the following way:

```
ListView {
    width: 100; height: 100

    model: myModel                     // injected QList<QObject*> context property
    delegate: Rectangle {
        height: 25
        width: 100
        color: model.modelData.color   // without "modelData" it would not work
        Text { text: name }
    }
}
```

**The same applies for nested properties.** If our `QObject`-derived object has a `QObject` property, like in your case, we can retrieve it via `modelData` and then access it's properties. So, for instance with the `customer` property, we would have something like this in the delegate:

```
Text { text: model.modelData.customer.name }
```

That's true for `ListView` et similia whereas I'm not sure it could be done directly with `TableView`. One possible workaround would be to combine the usage of the `QObject`-derived role with `styleData.value`. You can define the usage of the role in the `role` property and access the inner property inside the `styleData.value`. A solution for your case would look like the following (assuming `myModel` is a context property as the example above):

```
TableView  {
    width: 100; height: 100

    model: myModel

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "customer"
        title: "Kunde"
        width: 100

        delegate: Text {
            text: styleData.value.name  // accessing the property
        }
    }

    itemDelegate: Item {   }            // should be set to empty to avoid warnings
}
```

A downside of this approach is that you should implement a delegate for each column.